# Apps Crash when I change the orientation

Tags: android

Actually I am new on android and I am making a small android app for me to capture a photo and upload it to a web server, I've found some example code to do it.

The problem is that it works great on both landscape or portrait when I start the apps, but if I change the orientation from landscape to portrait or from portrait to landscape, it crashed.

Here is the log by Eclipse:

```
04-26 13:04:36.380: I/dalvikvm(887): threadid=3: reacting to signal 
3 04-26 13:04:36.510: I/dalvikvm(887): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' 
04-26 13:04:36.880: I/dalvikvm(887): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3 
04-26 13:04:36.890: I/dalvikvm(887): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' 
04-26 13:04:37.180: D/gralloc_goldfish(887): Emulator without GPU emulation detected. 
04-26 13:04:37.390: I/dalvikvm(887): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3 
04-26 13:04:37.530: I/dalvikvm(887): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' 
04-26 13:07:26.370: D/HEE(887): /mnt/sdcard/neosoft/ocr/photo/IMG_20130426_130726.jpg 
04-26 13:07:27.840: D/dalvikvm(887): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 128K, 3% free 9168K/9415K, paused 404ms 
04-26 13:07:44.929: D/AndroidRuntime(887): Shutting down VM 
04-26 13:07:44.929: W/dalvikvm(887): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.atakephoto1/com.example.atakephoto1.Photo1Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:123) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.example.atakephoto1.Photo1Activity.onCreate(Photo1Activity.java:139) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920) 
04-26 13:07:44.990: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  ... 12 more 04-26 13:07:45.751: I/dalvikvm(887): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3 
04-26 13:07:45.760: I/dalvikvm(887): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Here is my java code:

```
package com.example.atakephoto1;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
public class Photo1Activity extends Activity {
//private AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = null;
public static String image_file_path;
public static String php_upload_url;
public static String photoPath;
String TAG="tag";
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
SQLiteDatabase db;
public String db_name = "config";
public String table_name = "config";
NewListDataSQL helper = new NewListDataSQL(Photo1Activity.this, db_name);
AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {
      public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {

      }
};


public static boolean exists(String URLName){
    try {
      HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
      HttpURLConnection con =
         (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
      con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

      return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return false;
    }
}

protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
       .setMessage(mymessage)
       .setTitle(title)
       .setCancelable(true)
       .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel,
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){}
          })
       .show();
}

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // some work that needs to be done on orientation change
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo1);

    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select value from config where name='image_save_path'", null);
    int rows_num = cursor.getCount();
    if(rows_num != 0) {
     cursor.moveToFirst(); 
     for(int i=0; i<rows_num; i++) {
      String strCr = cursor.getString(0);
      photoPath = strCr;
      cursor.moveToNext();
     }
    }
    cursor.close();
    Cursor cursor_php = db.rawQuery("select value from config where name='php_upload_url'", null);

    int rows_num_php = cursor_php.getCount();
    if(rows_num_php != 0) {
        cursor_php.moveToFirst(); 
     for(int i=0; i<rows_num_php; i++) {
      String strCr = cursor_php.getString(0);
      php_upload_url = strCr;
      cursor_php.moveToNext();
     }
    }
    cursor_php.close(); 

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    //final Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
    for(int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++)
    {
        if(sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
            size = sizes.get(i);
    }
    parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
    parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    parameters.setSceneMode(Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
    parameters.setWhiteBalance(Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
    parameters.setExposureCompensation(0);
    parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    parameters.setJpegQuality(100);



    List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if (focusModes.contains(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)){
        parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO); 
    }

    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);    


    final FrameLayout frame01 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    frame01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
        }
    });




 // Add a listener to the Capture button
    final Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // get an image from the camera
                captureButton.setEnabled(false);
                mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

            }
        }
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_photo1, menu);
    return true;
}

private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}    

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
                //e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            image_file_path = pictureFile.getPath();
            Log.d("HEE",pictureFile.getPath());
            FileUploadTask fileuploadtask = new FileUploadTask();  
            fileuploadtask.execute();
            mCamera.startPreview();
            final Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
            captureButton.setEnabled(true);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
      return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(filepath, photoPath );
    if(!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        Log.d("HERE",photoPath );
        try
        {
            mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
            Log.d("HERE","after");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("HERE",e.getMessage().toString());
        }

    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

 class FileUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog = null;  
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;  
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;  
        String pathToOurFile = image_file_path;
        String urlServer = php_upload_url;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";  
        String twoHyphens = "--";  
        String boundary = "*****";  

        File uploadFile = new File(pathToOurFile);  
        long totalSize = uploadFile.length(); // Get size of file, bytes  

        @Override  
        protected void onPreExecute() {  
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Photo1Activity.this);  
            dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");  
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);  
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);  
            dialog.setProgress(0);  
            dialog.show();  
        }  

        @Override  
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... arg0) {  

            long length = 0;  
            int progress;  
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;  
            byte[] buffer;  
            int maxBufferSize = 256 * 1024;

            try {  
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));  

                URL url = new URL(urlServer);  
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  

                // Set size of every block for post  
                connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(256 * 1024);// 256KB  

                // Allow Inputs & Outputs  
                connection.setDoInput(true);  
                connection.setDoOutput(true);  
                connection.setUseCaches(false);  

                // Enable POST method  
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");  
                connection.setRequestProperty("Charset", "UTF-8");  
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",  
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);  

                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(  
                connection.getOutputStream());  
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);  
                outputStream  
                        .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""  
                                + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);  
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);  

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();  
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);  
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];  

                // Read file  
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                while (bytesRead > 0) {  
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  
                    length += bufferSize;  
                    progress = (int) ((length * 100) / totalSize);  
                    publishProgress(progress);  

                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();  
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);  
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  
                }  
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);  
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens  
                        + lineEnd);  
                publishProgress(100);  

                // Responses from the server (code and message)  
                // int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();  
                // String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();  

                fileInputStream.close();  
                outputStream.flush();  
                outputStream.close();  

            } catch (Exception ex) {  

            }  
            return null;  
        }  

        @Override  
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {  
            dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);  
        }  

        @Override  
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {  
            try {  
                dialog.dismiss();  
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            } catch (Exception e) {  
            }  
        }  

    } 

}
```

Comment: Have you prepared separate layout for landscape mode ? Because when the orientation changes from Landscpe to portrait or viceversa, all the views gets destroyed and new views are created, which you are going to provide by creating separate layout xml for landscape.

Comment: Can you please tell me more about how to do it?

Comment: you have error in Photo1Activity.jav line number 13 -->com.example.atakephoto1.Photo1Activity.onCreate(Photo1Activity.java:139) i think problem is diffrent layout.

Answer (score 1):

try to use

> < activity name= ".YourActivity"
>   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>

in manifest file

By declaring this android will manage itself state of your activity. Probably it will stop crashing activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following attribute in manifest file of your activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: line 139  Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

Comment: Another learner encouraged to use a hack and avoid the correct way to code Android apps and *fix* rather than avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to Call mCamera.release() to release the camera in onPause()
and reopen the camera  in onResume() using mCamera.reconnect()

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to you activity in manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
</activity>
```

In the YourActivity.java

Append the following code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Let me know if this is still not working.